# How can I find the input with a specific ID using the React Testing Library?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-testing-library

So when I try to catch `input` by `getByTestId` I get an error:

> TestingLibraryElementError: Unable to find an element by: [data-testid="Name"]

I've changed method to `queryByTestId` and I'd been getting error:

> Unable to fire a "change" event - please provide a DOM element.

I found out that if I enter following code:

```
expect(input).toBeNull;
```

I don't get any errors at all and test is passed.

**AddUser.test.js:**

```
import React from 'react';
import '@testing-library/jest-dom';
import AddUser from 'views/AddUser';
import Dashboard from 'views/AddUser';
import { screen, fireEvent } from '@testing-library/react';
import { renderWithProviders } from 'helpers/renderWithProviders';

describe('Input With Button', () => {
  it('Renders the component', () => {
    renderWithProviders(
      <>
        <AddUser />
        <Dashboard />
      </>
    );
    const input = screen.queryByTestId('Name');
    console.log(input);
    expect(input).toBeNull; // PASSED!

    fireEvent.change(input, { target: { value: 'Andrew' } }); // ERROR!
    // fireEvent.change(screen.getByTestId('Attendance'), { target: { value: '89%' } });
    // fireEvent.change(screen.getByTestId('Average'), { target: { value: '4.1' } });
    // fireEvent.click(screen.getByText('Add'));
    // screen.getByText('Andrew');
  });
});
```

**AddUser.js:**

```
// ...
return (
        <ViewWrapper as="form" onSubmit={handleSubmitUser}>
          <Title>Add new student</Title>
          <FormField label="Name" id="name" name="name" value={formValues.name} onChange={handleInputChange} />
          <FormField label="Attendance" id="attendance" name="attendance" value={formValues.attendance} onChange={handleInputChange} />
          <FormField label="Average" id="average" name="average" value={formValues.average} onChange={handleInputChange} />
          <Button type="submit">Add</Button>
        </ViewWrapper>
      );
// ...
```

**FormField.js:**

```
// ...
return (
<Wrapper>
  <Label htmlFor={id}>{label}</Label>
  <Input name={name} id={id} type={type} value={value} onChange={onChange} data-testid={label} />
</Wrapper>
);
// ...
```

**HTML Output of input element:**

```
<input name="name" id="name" type="text" data-testid="Name" class="sc-gsDKAQ dfgpGW" value="">
                                         ------ HERE ------
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Is the element being rendered? Can you use something like [screen.debug](https://testing-library.com/docs/queries/about#screendebug) to make sure the element is in your DOM?

Comment: `toBeNull` is a method, so you need to call it. `expect(input).toBeNull()`

Comment: What is `renderWithProviders` doing ?

Comment: @prohit `screen.debug` returns console.log with <body> <div /> </body>.
@GabrielePetrioli After calling toBeNull it still passes the test.
@GabrielePetrioli renderWithProviders? Here is [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/UkUaCL8V).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
export const renderWithProviders = ({ children }) => { // here
  return render(
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <UsersProvider>{children}</UsersProvider>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
};
```

I shouldn't destructurize children... it should look like this:

```
export const renderWithProviders = (children) => { // here
  return render(
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <UsersProvider>{children}</UsersProvider>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
};
```

It fixed the issue.